# How do I prevent special characters from being generated by the Ctrl key in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm building a little hotkey trainer for StarCraft2 (it's a C# Console application). But I'm struggling to capture Ctrl+ combinations, because certain Ctrl-combinations generate special characters.

For example, when pressing Ctrl+O, Console.ReadKey() won't capture the 'o' character, but rather a special starry '☼' character.  How do I prevent this and ensure Ctrl just acts as a modifier key and nothing else?

PS: I know about handling Ctrl+C specifically, so I'm more concerned about the other keys.

Here is a simple code example. Try capturing and outputting Ctrl+O

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var pressed = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(pressed.KeyChar);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried Console.ReadKey(true) to intercept the character?

Comment: Translate them AFTER you acquired them. If character <= 24 then + 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Console.ReadKey` you have everything you need using `Key` instead of `KeyChar`:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine(keyInfo.Key);
Console.WriteLine(keyInfo.Modifier);
```

As explained on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.consolekeyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), the `KeyChar` is the representation of the key combination (key + modifiers), and `Key` is the key the user pressed.

Additionally, if you don't want the `KeyChar` to appear on the screen, you can intercept the key using `Console.ReadKey(true)`.

Comment: Ah, your clarification regarding what KeyChar is for makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: @willem I agree, using the ConsoleKey enumeration is quite annoying. However, how will you intercept the "F1 - F12" keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information from the `ConsoleKeyInfo` object returned by `Console.ReadKey`

For Ctrl + O, the Ctrl key will be the `Modifier` property and the O key will be the `Key` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a ["trainer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trainer_(games)), reading StdIn is not going to cut it for you. This will only receive input when the Console App has focus. To read all keyboard input, i.e. when Start Craft 2 has focus, you need global hooking.

See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) for more info.

## October 2022 Update:

The provided article link is not yet stale, however it is highly out of date.  That being said, the general idea is still applicable and still accurate for Windows based programs.  For posterity (and StackOverflow link ideology) I will give a general and basic explanation of what the article is demonstrating:

Rather than subscribing to `Windows.Forms` key events or utilizing `Console.ReadKey()` it is possible to `P/Invoke` into `user32.dll` and use the native Windows hooks for keyboard and mouse events.  This allows you to actually circumvent the standard libraries that only provide high-level access to the Windows messages (see [Windows Message Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)) for these underlying events to perform more complicated tasks.

As the code is old and quite out of date, I will instead direct anyone reading this answer to a more current way of achieving this - though the process is still *exactly* the same.  Currently there are two newer options for this task, both of which are libraries designed to make `P/Invoke` operations easier and both of which are compatible with `.Net 6`

## PInvoke

## [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/pinvoke)

## [PInvoke.User32 Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvoke.User32)

This provides pre-compiled classes for invoking native libraries such as `user32.dll`.  This project is fully supported by the .Net Foundation.

## CsWin32

## [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin328)

This provides code-generation of classes for invoking native libraries such as `user32.dll` in almost the exact same way as the referenced `PInvoke` project.  This is a Microsoft project and as such should be relevant for quite some time, though it is still in beta at this time.  This is a much more efficient and streamlined alternative to `PInvoke`.

Comment: Ah, in this case a console window is actually fine. I'd just like to train for certain combinations, so no need for any games to be running in the background :)